# CSS on Favicon - Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails 4 app with bootstrap.

I have  a logo picture in my page header, that links back to the root path.

I am trying to fix the CSS so that when you hover on the logo, it doesn't appear with a black solid box behind part of the logo.

I want transparent background at all times. No hover styling and no visited styling.

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" style=" a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent;}; a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent;};
;
">
                  <%= link_to image_tag("favicon.ico", size: "25" ), root_path  %> 
                 </div>
```

I have tried to stop that styling but can't find what's forcing the black box.

ANOTHER ATTEMPT:

I tried removing the styling attributes from the html and putting them into a separate div tag:

I now have a div class called nav logo and replaced the reference to the style with:

```
<div class="col-md-4" class="navlogo">
                  <%= link_to image_tag("favicon.ico", size: "25" ), root_path  %> 
                 </div>
```

The div tag has:

```
.navlogo {
     a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color:none};
    a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:none};
    a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:none};
    a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:none};
}
```

The black box is still there. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: why are you using an .ico image? the favicon is only meant to be next to the title of the page (tab)...

Comment: I don't want to load the image twice

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify entire stylesheets inside style attributes and expect it to be respected by any matching descendents. style attribute is only used to specify inline css rules for the node to which it belongs.

So your style attribute does not have any effect. You may want to move the css inside a style tag.

If that does not solve the problem, please consider creating a jsfiddle so the issue may be reproduced.

Comment: I don't know what yo mean 'matching descendants'. That is the only place in which I use those attributes and that icon in the html. I also don't know what a node is, or what a 'node' belongs to. I don't know what a style tag is either. Do you mean a div tag?

Comment: I certainly do not mean a div tag when I explicitly mentioned style tag : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Comment: Please pick up a good book or online course on HTML fundamentals. Also consider putting in atleast some basic effort googling for answers before you ask questions.

Comment: Actually - I read all of the course materials on starting with css and html before asking. I googled each of the technical terms you used before responding to your comment. I asked because I could not construe your jargon to find meaning. Perhaps you could be mindful that there are people with a variety of skill levels trying to use this board.

Comment: also, in each other aspect of my project, I routinely use styling the way I have it set out in my question above to modify the css in my div tags. If others are reading this board and are confused by your declarations, the approach above does work to introduce css styling to modify or add to the styling in a div tag. I don't know why it didn't work in my above post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work when you split it out as a separate div tag with the styling in a separate div class.

```
<div class="col-md-4"> <div class="navlogo2">
                  <%= link_to image_tag("favicon.ico", size: "25" ), root_path  %> 
                 </div></div>
```